# Training Doc2vec with new data

Tags: document, word2vec, cpu-word, skip, doc2vec

I have a doc2vec model trained on documents with labels. I'm trying to continue training my model with model.train(). The new data comes with new labels as well, but, when I train it on more documents, the new labels aren't being recorded... Does anyone know what my problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

Gensim's `Doc2Vec` only learns its set of `tags` at the same time it learns the corpus vocabulary of unique words – during the first call to `.build_vocab()` on the original corpus.

When you train with additional examples that have either words or tags that aren't already known to the model, those words or tags are simply ignored.

(The `.build_vocab(…, update=True)` option that's available on `Word2Vec` to expand its vocabulary has never been fully applied to `Doc2Vec`, either with respect to `tags` or with respect to a [longstanding crashing bug](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1019). So it's not supported on `Doc2Vec`.)

Note that if it is your aim to create document-vectors that assist in some downstream-classification task, you may not want to supply your known-labels as `tags`, or at least not as a document's **only** tag.

The `tags` you supply to `Doc2Vec` are the units for which it learns vectors. If you have a million text examples, but only 5 different labels, if you feed those million examples into training each with only the label as a tag, the model is only learning 5 doc-vectors. It is, essentially, like you're training on only 5 mega-documents (passed in in chunks) – and thus 'summarizing' each label down to a single point in vector-space, when it might be far more useful to think of a label as covering a irregularly-shaped "point cloud".

So, you might instead want to use document-IDs rather than labels. (Or, labels *and* document-IDs.) Then, use the many varied vectors from all individual documents – rather than single vectors per label – to train some downstream classifier or clusterer.

And in that case, the arrival of documents with new labels might not require a full `Doc2Vec`-retraining. Instead, if the new documents still get useful vectors from inference on the older `Doc2Vec` model, those per-doc vectors may reflect enough about the new label's documents that downstream classifiers can learn to recognize them.

Ultiamtely, though, if you acquire much more training data, reflecting all new vocabularies & word-senses, the safest approach is to retrain a `Doc2Vec` model from scratch, using all data. Simply incremental training, even if it had official support, risks pulling those words/tags that appear in new data arbitrarily out-of-comparable-alignment with words/tags that were only trained in the original dataset. It is the interleaved co-training, alongside *all* other examples equally, which pushes-and-pulls all vectors in a model into useful relative arrangements.